# Cordova Emulator Not Installing App on Emulator Device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

Running:

```
sudo cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-6s, 11.1"
```

Builds the app just fine and the emulator loads, but the app isn't being installed on the emulator, or I just can't see the icon. There is an error before it loads the emulator:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/[username]/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/B95880CA-FE4D-4738-9E6A-D684584DA281/system.log
```

But I don't think that will prevent the app being installed? I know the app works because I can build in phonegap build and push to my actual iPhone X so there is something not right with the emulator.

EDIT:

This happens even on a fresh install of Xcode and Cordova and a brand new blank app created with cordova create command. Could this be something to do with my Mac always wanting sudo?

Comment: Every single time Apple releases an updated iOS version, they somehow find a way to break Cordova deployment. Make sure you have latest versions of everything like Cordova CLI and cordova-ios, and by latest I mean updated in the last few seconds, ahead of the Apple staff.

Comment: Thanks @andreszs I have actually installed Xcode , Cordova and iOS emulator fresh and still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Xcode, if you haven't already.

   a. Once installed, run Xcode and accept the license agreement.

   b. Go into Xcode Prefs (Cmd + ,), go to Downloads, and install "Command Line Tools for Xcode" (or something named similarily)
2. Install Homebrew (copy and paste the following into your terminal):

   `bash
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`
3. While still in terminal, run:

   `bash
   brew update
   brew doctor`

   a. If you haven't yet installed "Command Line Tools for Xcode", you will be told by brew doctor to install it. See step 1.b.

   b. If necessary, fix any other issues that brew doctor reports.
4. Install Node.js using Brew:

   `bash
   brew install node`
5. Install Cordova (formerly "PhoneGap") usind NPM (Node Package Manager):

   `bash
   sudo npm install -g cordova`
6. Install ios-sim plugin for Cordova (so you can launch iOS simulator directly):

   `bash
   sudo npm install -g ios-sim`
7. Create a Cordova project and add iOS as a platform
   `bash
   cordova create DirectoryName com.company.appname AppName
   cd DirectoryName
   cordova platform add ios`
8. Great, you're done! You should be able to run this repo by simply running:

   `bash
   cordova build ios
   cordova simulate ios`

Give it a few seconds and your iOS simulator with your Cordova app should appear right in front of you. Hooray!

from: https://gist.github.com/peteygao/9842159

Comment: all of this was done before I posted the problem, also a complete fresh Mac install today and still doesn't work. The emulator works but no app

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the fact that I always have to use SUDO for running cordova?